# Enable Function Chain Response for AWS API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless

The official guide for AWS API gateway introduces the way to use a lambda function to make responses to the API calls from the gateway. But it can only deal with one function, not for the condition of several functions call one by one.

For a solution, here are two to the best of my mind:

1. Use AWS Step Function services to bundle the function workflow.
2. Use one main thread function for orchestration.

Obviously, method 1 will bring extra fees, while method 2 needs a redundant function to run for long.

Could you please give me any help？

Comment: Not sure what kind of help you ask, since you already wrote the options yourself...

Answer (score 0):

If they must be completed one after another before you can return the result, use AWS Step Functions (like you said) to orchestrate this. Synchronous invocation of the other Lambda is also an option (though it's commonly an architectural smell and indicates other issues with your architecture - why are the Lambdas not combined if they need each other etc.)

For asynchronous invocation of the other function (fire and forget), either invoke the Lambda using [invocation type `Event`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-async.html) or even better would be to have an [SQS queue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html) in between the Lambdas for improved resiliency.